# Firebase Crashlytics NDK uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile task NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-plugin

I am working on project which requires android NDK crash reports.
I am using the firebase crashlytics SDK for reporting crashes in my app.
To enable NDK crash reporting I am following the documentation mention [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports-new-sdk).

The below task is executed successfully

```
gradle app:assembleBUILD_VARIANT
```

In the below task fails with a **NullPointerException**.

```
gradle app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT
```

Below is the stacktrace for the exception

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processDebugInfoEntry(DwarfDataParser.java:297)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processChildDebugInfoEntries(DwarfDataParser.java:269)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:194)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.readCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:173)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.readCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:139)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.parse(DwarfDataParser.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parseElf(ElfDataParser.java:132)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:39)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.ElfCSymFactory.createCSymFromFile(ElfCSymFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateFromDirectories(NdkCSymGenerator.java:44)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.generateNativeSymbolFile(Buildtools.java:157)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools$generateNativeSymbolFile$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.GenerateSymbolFileTask.generateSymbols(GenerateSymbolFileTask.groovy:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        ... 35 more
```

> I have tried
>
> - deleting the .gradle
> - Invalidate cache and restart
> - rebuilding the project
> - changing the gradle version
>
> None of the above solution has helped me out.
>
> It would be really helpful if anyone could help me out with this issue
>   or provide any directions which could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer for this, but I've just recently implemented Firebase Crashlytics for the NDK and made a small tutorial on how I did it [here](https://proandroiddev.com/setting-up-firebase-crashlytics-ndk-a7770a447d5f).

As per your stack trace, make sure your correctly applying the required plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

and that you're adding the required dependency too

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk'
```

In your app-level build file.